# Duplicate data when working with multiple tables. Clarification needed

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a very simple table as shown when query returning clean data `select * from Income where symbol = 'AAPL' and statementitem = 'Revenues' and periodtype="Annual";`

--

When I attempt to put together a report, I get 0 from someplace. **How can I remove the 0 to get a clean output?** *Where do these 0s come from?*

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _vars;
CREATE TABLE _vars(symbol);
INSERT INTO  _vars(symbol) VALUES ('AAPL');

SELECT distinct a.yearmonth, a.symbol, periodtype,

      case when a.statementitem = 'Revenues' AND a.periodtype = 'Annual' then (CASE WHEN (a.value is null or a.value = '') then 0 ELSE a.value  END) else 0 end Revenue,
      case when a.statementitem = 'Gross Profit' AND a.periodtype = 'Annual' then (CASE WHEN (a.value is null or a.value = '') then 0 ELSE a.value  END) else 0 end GrossProfit,
      case when a.statementitem = 'Selling General & Admin Expenses' AND a.periodtype = 'Annual' then (CASE WHEN (a.value is null or a.value = '') then 0 ELSE a.value  END) else 0 end GrossProfit

FROM _vars
INNER JOIN Income a ON a.symbol = _vars.symbol and a.periodtype = 'Annual'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st query contains 3 conditions:

```
WHERE symbol = 'AAPL' AND statementitem = 'Revenues' AND periodtype = 'Annual'
```

and the result is 10 rows.
Your 2nd query joins `_vars` to the table and since `_vars` contains only 1 row with the column `symbol` having value `'AAPL'` and you also apply the condition:

```
and a.periodtype = 'Annual'
```

in the `ON` clause, you are covering only 2 of the conditions of the 1st query.
You do not apply the condition:

```
statementitem = 'Revenues'
```

you are just checking it in:

```
case when a.statementitem = 'Revenues' AND .....
```

Checking a condition does not apply it.
This means that you get more rows in the results that are coming from all the rows that do not have `'Revenues'` in the column `statementitem` and the `CASE` expression returns `0` for these rows in the column `Revenue`.

Edit:
You should use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT a.yearmonth, a.symbol, a.periodtype,
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN a.statementitem = 'Revenues' THEN a.value END), 0) Revenue,
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN a.statementitem = 'Gross Profit' THEN a.value END), 0) GrossProfit,
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN a.statementitem = 'Selling General & Admin Expenses' THEN a.value END), 0) [Selling General & Admin Expenses]
FROM _vars INNER JOIN Income a 
ON a.symbol = _vars.symbol AND a.periodtype = 'Annual'
GROUP BY a.yearmonth, a.symbol, a.periodtype
```

Comment: Ok this is magic! I can't say I fully understand what you did there with COALESCE, but it works!!!!!

Comment: If you ractually have `''` values in the column `value` then replace: `THEN a.value END` with `THEN NULLIF(a.value, '') END` in all 3 cases. But it would be better to just update the table with: `UPDATE Income SET value = null WHERE value = ''`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 0 because of the below case statement. If your value is null and statementitem is not 'Revenues' and periodtype is not 'Annual',  you are a making it as 0

```
case when a.statementitem = 'Revenues' AND a.periodtype = 'Annual' 
then (CASE WHEN (a.value is null or a.value = '') then 0 ELSE a.value  END) else 0
```

You can get rid of these if you don't want 0's in your result.

This will give you without 0's but with nulls,

```
SELECT distinct a.yearmonth, a.symbol, periodtype,
a.value as Revenue
FROM _vars
inner JOIN Income a ON a.symbol = _vars.symbol
where  a.statementitem = 'Revenues' and a.periodtype = 'Annual'
```

This query will give you no nulls,

```
SELECT distinct a.yearmonth, a.symbol, periodtype,
 a.value  as Revenue
FROM _vars
inner JOIN Income a ON a.symbol = _vars.symbol 
where  a.statementitem = 'Revenues' and a.periodtype = 'Annual'
and (a.value is null or a.value = '')
```

Without Inner join,

```
SELECT distinct a.yearmonth, a.symbol, periodtype,
a.value  as Revenue
from Income a
where  a.statementitem = 'Revenues' and a.periodtype = 'Annual'
and (a.value is null or a.value = '')
and a.symbol in ('AAPL');
```

Comment: Right. "case" version is an evolution from Inner Joins. I had 30 of them before and things got slow :). Any way to avoid inner join and retain performance? Even better ... can I change the logic to say " If you don't find `Revenues` at all, then put 0 in `Values`.

Comment: Yes you can get rid of inner join as well. But you need to defile symbols in WHERE clause. Provided you the query in the answer session

Comment: Jim, I will update my question in a sec ... please stand by

Comment: Sure, will be on hold

Comment: Updated. Please consider that I will join in from multiple tables to get the final report. How can I change things without innner joins? Again, my main concern is that sometimes I will get no "Revenues" column at all. In such a case I'd like to put it in and fill up with 0.

Comment: So, only when `value` is null it should change to 0

Answer (score 1):

these duplicate data are because of records that are (AAPL,Annual) but are not (Revenues).you should move the condition of statementitem in where cluse or in join condition:

```
SELECT distinct a.yearmonth, a.symbol, periodtype,isnull(a.value,0)  as Revenue
FROM _vars
inner JOIN Income a ON a.symbol = _vars.symbol 
where  a.statementitem = 'Revenues' and a.periodtype = 'Annual'
```

or

```
SELECT distinct a.yearmonth, a.symbol, periodtype,isnull(a.value,0) as revenue
FROM _vars
inner JOIN Income a ON a.symbol = _vars.symbol 
   and a.statementitem = 'Revenues' and a.periodtype = 'Annual'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

With Join

```
SELECT distinct a.yearmonth, a.symbol, periodtype,
case when a.statementitem = 'Revenues' then (CASE WHEN (a.value is null or a.value = '') then 0 ELSE a.value  END) else 0 end Revenue,
case when a.statementitem = 'Gross Profit' then (CASE WHEN (a.value is null or a.value = '') then 0 ELSE a.value  END) else 0 end GrossProfit,
case when a.statementitem = 'Selling General & Admin Expenses' then (CASE WHEN (a.value is null or a.value = '') then 0 ELSE a.value  END) else 0 end GrossProfit
FROM _vars
INNER JOIN Income a ON a.symbol = _vars.symbol 
where a.periodtype = 'Annual'
```

Without Join

```
SELECT distinct a.yearmonth, a.symbol, periodtype,
case when a.statementitem = 'Revenues' then (CASE WHEN (a.value is null or a.value = '') then 0 ELSE a.value  END) else 0 end Revenue,
case when a.statementitem = 'Gross Profit' then (CASE WHEN (a.value is null or a.value = '') then 0 ELSE a.value  END) else 0 end GrossProfit,
case when a.statementitem = 'Selling General & Admin Expenses' then (CASE WHEN (a.value is null or a.value = '') then 0 ELSE a.value  END) else 0 end GrossProfit
FROM Income a 
where a.periodtype = 'Annual'
and a.symbol in ('AAPL');
```

Comment: Probably this will provide you a proper solution